# IndexError: list index out of range python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm newbie with python and just stuck with my code. Basically I need check Norwegian VATs, in this case I'm using http://w2.brreg.no/enhet/sok/detalj.jsp?orgnr= website, . When I put in VatNo correct one I get:

```
f = re.findall("Du har oppgitt et ugyldig organisasjonsnummer",page)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But if I put incorrect VAT then working well..

This is how my code looks like:

```
import requests
import re
VatNo = '997814169' #ValidVat

def VatChecker():
    page = requests.get("http://w2.brreg.no/enhet/sok/detalj.jsp?orgnr="+VatNo).text

    x = "Du har oppgitt et ugyldig organisasjonsnummer"
    f = re.findall("Du har oppgitt et ugyldig organisasjonsnummer",page)[0]

    if f==x:
        print ("Invalid VAT")

    else:
        print ("Valid VAT")

VatChecker()
```

Have you got any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: Seems that `re.findall("Du har oppgitt et ugyldig organisasjonsnummer",page)` returned empty list.

Comment: to expand on ^^, page could be empty or f could be empty.

Comment: You should check the return value from `re.findall` before trying to index into it.  If it's an empty list, then of course trying to reference the first element will produce an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that `re.findall("Du har oppgitt et ugyldig organisasjonsnummer",page)` returns an empty list, as mentioned by @sashaaero.

To correct the code you can do:

```
f = re.findall("Du har oppgitt et ugyldig organisasjonsnummer",page)
if (len(f)>0):
    if f==x:
        print ("Invalid VAT")

    else:
        print ("Valid VAT")
```

Comment: thanks you guys for help!! now it's working perfectly :)